# Mysql query on three tables, where third table has multiple queried returns

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables, listing and listing_data.

Listings Table

```
** listing_id | some_field | some_other_field **
**     1      |    value   |     value        **
**     2      |    value   |     value        **
**     3      |    value   |     value        **
**     4      |    value   |     value        **
```

Listing Data

```
**  data_id  | listing_id | field_name | field_value **
**    1      |      1     |    value   |      1      **
**    2      |      1     |    other   |      3      **
**    3      |      2     |    value   |      5      **
**    4      |      3     |    value   |      6      **
**    5      |      3     |    other   |      7      **
**    6      |      3     |    value   |      6      **
```

I need to query the table so that I can get all the fields from the listings and listing_data table, and values that meet a certain criteria on the listing data table.

IE. WHERE listing_data.field_name = 'value' AND listing_data.field_value BETWEEN '1' AND '3' AND listing_data.field_name = 'other' AND listing_data.field_value BETWEEN '3' AND '4'

Right now I have:

```
SELECT l . * , d . *
FROM listings l
JOIN listing_data d ON d.listing_id = l.listing_id
WHERE (
d.field_name = 'val1'
AND field_value
BETWEEN 1
AND 1
)
OR (
d.field_name = 'val2'
AND field_value
BETWEEN 3
AND 4
)
```

This works, but only returns val1, val2 fields values. These are just to search on but I actually need all field values (ie. val3, val4, etc.). Also, the search need to be AND not OR, because I just want results that match all search criteria. Changing the OR to AND in this statement returns nothing. I know it is because you cannot match two different field names (field_name cannot be equal to val1 AND val2)

Comment: I need to edit this so that it is more clearly stated. I think they way I had it posted did not cover enerything.

Answer (score 0):

You're specifying the table alias for listings as `l` - you need to refer to it as that instead of the original name:

```
SELECT l.*, i.*
FROM listings l, listing_images i
-- ...
```

Comment: This fixed the unknown table issue, however the query is returning empty results when it should return something. I am going to edit my initial post because as it turns out I am not going to query for images here because if the listing has no images that listing is not included in the results.

Comment: I got it to work by making aliases for each searched field name. I believe from my research I am just going to have to get the full gambit of data inside by loop, but still working on it. Here is the current query SELECT distinct(listings.listing_id), listings.*
FROM listings, listing_data `val1`,listing_data `val2` 
WHERE 
(listings.listing_id = `val1`.listing_id) 
AND (listings.listing_id = `val2`.listing_id) 
AND (`val1`.field_name = 'val1' AND ( `val1`.field_value BETWEEN 3 AND 4)) 
AND (`val2`.field_name = 'val2' AND ( `val2`.field_value BETWEEN 1 AND 2))

Comment: Why do you need a list of **all** field names? I can't see how that data structure will fit with your current query's structure, unless you select distinct names and join a result to each of those... If this is for a server side script like PHP, run a seperate query to get all the field names

Comment: Yes, I realized that after posting. I will retrieve the fields once I loop through the listings from the search. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
select listings.*, listing_images.*
from listings l 
  inner join listing_images i 
  on i.listing_id = l.listing_id
  inner join listing_data d
  on d.listing_id = l.listing_id
where (d.field_name = 'val1' 
  and field_value between 1 and 2) or
  (d.field_name = 'val2' and 
  field_value between 3 and 4)
```

I also fixed your WHERE clause to what I think you are after.  The way you had it would not have returned any records.

Comment: Going to try this. I was about to comment that I am removing the images table from this query, as it will skip a liting with no image.

Comment: Also, I need the field queries to be 'AND', because I only want results that match both statements

Comment: I have this now select l.*
from listings l 
  join listing_data d
  on d.listing_id = l.listing_id
where (d.field_name = 'baths' 
  and field_value between 1 and 2) or
  (d.field_name = 'beds' and 
  field_value between 3 and 4)
GROUP BY l.listing_id and it returns just the data from the listings table. I am search on listing_data criteria, but actual need all the data returned
where (d.field_name = 'baths' 
  and field_value between 1 and 2) or
  (d.field_name = 'beds' and 
  field_value between 3 and 4)

Comment: It technically works, but is only returning the searched upon values from the data table. Even though I am searching for criteria on fields val1 and val2, i need the values for all the fields for the listing_id, ie. val3, val4, val5